# MVC4 ReportViewer with Oracle stored procedure REF_CURSOR or OUT parameter?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ref-cursor, out-parameters

I have an MVC4 project and I am using the Entity Framework to make a connection to the database where my Oracle stored procedure "lives".  I am able to connect successfully and I can see that procedure in the Server Explorer.  I am also able to test that procedure by right-clicking on it and executing the Run command with an input parameter.  I see the results displayed in the results panel.  My question is this?  What is the correct approach to get the data back so I can return it in my View by way of an Action Result; do I use OUT parameters in my stored procedure OR should I use a REF_CURSOR?